# What does "agreeable skeptic" mean?

Tags: soul-2020

Souls describing their personalities:

> I'm an **agreeable skeptic** who's cautious yet flamboyant. I'm an
> irritable wallflower who's dangerously curious.  I'm a manipulative
> megalomaniac who's intensely opportunistic.

What does "agreeable skeptic" mean?
Both words are so quite different.

Comment: What do you mean by the words are different?  Skeptic doesn't necessarily mean confrontational; they describe separate aspects of a personality.

Comment: maybe intended as something other than the pergorative 'militant atheiest'

Comment: I don't believe the combination of words means anything different from the words separately. In other words "agreeable skeptic" just means they are both agreeable and a skeptic.

Comment: May be a simple language issue.  "Agreeable" doesn't really mean "willing to agree", it means "likeable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember these are not quite “souls describing their personalities” at this point yet, these are proto-souls who have not yet found their spark.

The premise of the film, as experienced in this scene is that developing new souls are guided by mentors, who have already lived their lives on Earth and will help new souls find their passions. Overseers—Picasso-esque line drawings (Alice Braga, Richard Ayoade and Wes Studi) all named Jerry—help to assign each soul a personality before birth.

When this precocious yet budding soul-to-be then barks: “I’m an agreeable skeptic who’s cautious yet flamboyant,” it doesn’t yet know which personality element will be it’s spark.

But at this time, it is a proto-soul who is not easily convinced about things who has doubts and reservations, but may be willing to agree and generally be enjoyable and pleasant, even if they are careful to avoid potential problems as attract attention to themselves because of their exuberance or style.

The good thing is they will get some assistance in sorting that all out before starting their new life.